# StandardJarScanner Error

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I have placed the spring-mvc jar files in the web-inf/lib folder and included jstl 1.2 in the lib folder. All the required jars are in the lib folder. For Spring.tld jar, I have checked in the stack overflow that we can add springweb-mvc jar in the lib folder will resolve it. But I am getting this error again and again.I have included the tomcat jars in the buildpath. Please let me know If I am missing anything else.

```
 HTTP Status 500 - Unable to initialize TldLocationsCache: org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner cannot be cast to org.apache.tomcat.JarScanner

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    type Exception report

    message Unable to initialize TldLocationsCache: org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner cannot be cast to org.apache.tomcat.JarScanner

    description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

    exception 

    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to initialize TldLocationsCache: org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner cannot be cast to org.apache.tomcat.JarScanner
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache.init(TldLocationsCache.java:252)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache.getLocation(TldLocationsCache.java:205)
        org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.getTldLocation(JspCompilationContext.java:607)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:409)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:475)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1427)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:242)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:102)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:198)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
        org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)


    root cause 

    java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner cannot be cast to org.apache.tomcat.JarScanner
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.JarScannerFactory.getJarScanner(JarScannerFactory.java:39)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache.init(TldLocationsCache.java:243)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache.getLocation(TldLocationsCache.java:205)
        org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.getTldLocation(JspCompilationContext.java:607)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:409)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:475)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1427)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:242)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:102)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:198)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
        org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)


    note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.34 logs.


    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Apache Tomcat/7.0.34
```

Comment: This looks like the same error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400445/spring-mvc-java-lang-classcastexception

Comment: yes, but this time I have included the jars

Comment: As you have mentioned 15400445 question, I have removed all the tomcat jars from the web-inf/lib am getting the same error. I tried removing from deployment assembly alo(tomcat jars). I tried all the stack overflow questions related to this and tried to fix this, but its not working, can you please share spring.tld.jar.

Comment: I tried adding standard_1.1.2_jar for taglibs in web-inf/lib folder, still am getting the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

I remove tomcat-api-7.0.82.jar
and edit webapp-runner dependency in pom.xml to:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
    <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.82.0</version>
     <exclusions>
         <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
     </exclusions>
</dependency>
```